# SOLR - indexing documents with pairs key/value

Tags: solr, lucene, indexing, solr4

Here, it's my document after import from mongoDB :

```
    documents": [
    {
      "uid": [
        1
      ],
      "body": [
        ""
      ],
      "field_section": [
        {
          "nid": "3"
        }
      ],
      "node_panels": [
        {
          "use_node_panel": false
        }
      ],
      "field_urltitle": [
        {
          "value": null
        }
      ],
      "field_test_content": [
        {
          "value": null
        }
      ],
      "type": [
        "book"
      ],
      "changed": [
        1354017880
      ],
      "nodewords_nodetype_override": [
        false
      ],
      "field_content_extract": [
        {
          "nid": null
        }
      ],
      "created": [
        1320142582
      ],
      "taxonomy": [
        {
          "796": {
            "tid": 796,
            "vid": 2,
            "name": "Roman Français",
            "description": "",
            "weight": "0"
          }
        }
      ],
      "vid": [
        595023
      ],
      "field_comment": [
        {
          "value": null
        }
      ],
      "field_description": [
        {
          "value": "<p>\"Je ne sais pas, écrit l'auteur, si quelqu'un avant moi a jamais tenté de réunir la totalité des souvenirs qu'il a gardés de ses dix ou onze premières années. J'ai cherché à les reproduire non seulement sous leur forme objective d'actes, d'attitudes ou de jugements, mais aussi avec la saveur subjective que ces faits eurent pour moi à l'époque. Car ce qui importe le plus, ici, ce n'est pas tant l'exactitude historique des faits rapportés (encore que je me sois efforcé de la respecter), c'est leur retentissement, la trace qu'ils laissent dans la vie intérieure de l'enfant, puis dans celle de l'adulte, jusqu'à sa mort sans doute\". </p>",
          "format": "7"
        }
      ],
      "field_content_continue_with": [
        {
          "nid": null
        }
      ],
      "field_content_celebrity": [
        {
          "nid": "591932",
          "type": "50"
        }
      ],
      "field_content_day": [
        {
          "value": null,
          "timezone": "Europe/Paris",
          "timezone_db": "Europe/Paris",
          "date_type": "datestamp"
        }
      ],
      "field_evene_modified": [
        {
          "value": null
        }
      ],
      "field_content_video": [
        {
          "nid": null
        }
      ],
      "field_fnac_url": [
        {
          "url": "http://livre.fnac.com/a4069141/Quentin-Jacares-Le-passe-interieur",
          "title": null,
          "attributes": []
        }
      ],
      "format": [
        0
      ],
      "log": [
        "Created/updated by FeedsNodeProcessor"
      ],
      "field_external_category": [
        {
          "value": "a:2:{i:0;s:23:\"Littérature française\";i:1;s:0:\"\";}"
        }
      ],
      "field_publication_date": [
        {
          "value": 1320102000,
          "timezone": "Europe/Paris",
          "timezone_db": "Europe/Paris",
          "date_type": "datestamp"
        }
      ],
      "picture": [
        "files/user_pictures/picture-1.png"
      ],
      "field_content_more": [
        {
          "nid": null
        }
      ],
      "field_image": [
        {
          "fid": "200052",
          "uid": "1",
          "filename": "591933.gif",
          "filepath": "files/book/591933.gif",
          "filemime": "image/gif",
          "filesize": "33725",
          "status": "1",
          "timestamp": "1320142582",
          "origname": "decitre-import.gif",
          "list": null,
          "data": []
        }
      ],
      "field_selection": [
        {
          "value": null
        }
      ],
      "promote": [
        1
      ],
      "last_comment_timestamp": [
        1320142586
      ],
      "teaser": [
        ""
      ],
      "field_content_anecdote": [
        {
          "nid": null
        }
      ],
      "revision_timestamp": [
        1354017880
      ],
      "language": [
        ""
      ],
      "comment": [
        2
      ],
      "field_page_number": [
        {
          "value": 293
        }
      ],
      "page_title": [
        false
      ],
      "field_ads_keywords": [
        {
          "value": null
        }
      ],
      "data": [
        "a:5:{s:14:\"picture_delete\";i:0;s:14:\"picture_upload\";s:0:\"\";s:13:\"form_build_id\";s:37:\"form-195606921d7a71b9a51bf3bcdc018f38\";s:5:\"fbuid\";s:15:\"100000792647737\";s:9:\"nodewords\";a:9:{s:8:\"abstract\";a:1:{s:5:\"value\";s:0:\"\";}s:9:\"canonical\";a:1:{s:5:\"value\";s:0:\"\";}s:9:\"copyright\";a:1:{s:5:\"value\";s:0:\"\";}s:11:\"description\";a:1:{s:5:\"value\";s:0:\"\";}s:8:\"keywords\";a:1:{s:5:\"value\";s:0:\"\";}s:13:\"revisit-after\";a:1:{s:5:\"value\";s:1:\"1\";}s:6:\"robots\";a:2:{s:5:\"value\";a:6:{s:9:\"noarchive\";i:0;s:8:\"nofollow\";i:0;s:7:\"noindex\";i:0;s:5:\"noodp\";i:0;s:9:\"nosnippet\";i:0;s:6:\"noydir\";i:0;}s:11:\"use_default\";i:0;}s:8:\"dc.title\";a:1:{s:5:\"value\";s:0:\"\";}s:8:\"location\";a:2:{s:8:\"latitude\";s:0:\"\";s:9:\"longitude\";s:0:\"\";}}}"
      ],
      "field_external_id": [
        {
          "value": 9782310010054
        }
      ],
      "field_publication_first": [
        {
          "value": null,
          "timezone": "Europe/Paris",
          "timezone_db": "Europe/Paris",
          "date_type": "datestamp"
        }
      ],
      "field_prize": [
        {
          "nid": null,
          "label_1": "",
          "label_2": ""
        }
      ],
      "field_content_critique": [
        {
          "nid": null
        }
      ],
      "field_book_citation": [
        {
          "nid": null
        }
      ],
      "title": [
        "Le passé intérieur"
      ],
      "_id": [
        "org.bson.types.ObjectId:50b4aca6a6937d876782cbc3"
      ],
      "field_fnac_id": [
        {
          "value": null
        }
      ],
      "name": [
        "admin"
      ],
      "path": [
        "livres/livre/quentin-jacares-le-passe-interieur-591933.php"
      ],
      "field_isbn": [
        {
          "value": 9782310010054
        }
      ],
      "field_price": [
        {
          "value": "20.72"
        }
      ],
      "revision_uid": [
        0
      ],
      "tnid": [
        0
      ],
      "field_author_v2": [
        {
          "value": null
        }
      ],
      "field_subtitle": [
        {
          "value": "Une enfance dans la Belgique d'avant la guerre"
        }
      ],
      "field_label": [
        {
          "nid": "120600"
        }
      ],
      "comment_count": [
        0
      ],
      "nid": [
        591933
      ],
      "moderate": [
        0
      ],
      "field_site": [
        {
          "url": null,
          "title": null,
          "attributes": false
        }
      ],
      "field_v2_full": [
        {
          "value": null
        }
      ],
      "sticky": [
        0
      ],
      "field_v2_id": [
        {
          "value": null
        }
      ],
      "translate": [
        0
      ],
      "field_content_photo": [
        {
          "nid": null
        }
      ],
      "opengraph_meta": [
        {
          "title": "",
          "description": "",
          "image": "http://www.evene.fr/sites/all/themes/evene/images/logos/logo-evene.png",
          "type": "",
          "url": "",
          "latitude": "",
          "longitude": "",
          "street-address": "",
          "locality": "",
          "region": "",
          "postal-code": "",
          "country-name": "",
          "email": "",
          "phone_number": "",
          "fax_number": "",
          "site_name": "Evene.fr"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

I would'like ton configure to index all fields with keys and value.

i have tried with

```
<field name="field_description" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

but the result is empty for object with a sub key.

result :

```
uid : 1 
body : 
spell : Le passé intérieur 
body_exact : 
type : book 
vid : 595023 
picture : files/user_pictures/picture-1.png 
teaser : 
title : Le passé intérieur 
title_exact : Le passé intérieur 
title_exact_ : Le passé intérieur 
_id : 50b4aca6a6937d876782cbc3 
path : livres/livre/quentin-jacares-le-passe-interieur-591933.php 
comment_count : 0 
nid : 591933 
_version_ : 1438259731338625024 
timestamp : Wed Jun 19 10:42:45 CEST 2013 
score : 1.0
```

Have you a solution to do it

Comment: Can you specify which sub key are you talking about?

Comment: for example: field_description->value

Answer (score 0):

Considering the example you gave, seems like you exported your mongoDB as a JSON format. So if you want to import JSON into Solr, by default it won’t handle nested values. You need to use the proper declaration for it to work. For example, in your example, you need to have the following format for the field_description field:

```
{
"field_description":{
  "value":"Je ne sais pas, ecrit l'auteur, si quelqu'un avant moi a jamais tente de reunir la totalite des souvenirs qu'il a gardzs de ses dix ou onze premieres annees.",
  "format":7
} }
```

If you’re not using the JSON format but another importer for your mongoDB/Solr connection, please mention which one it is so that I can help you further.

Comment: It'an output from Drupal to Mongodb. This format cannot be change.

Answer (score 0):

A solution:

Use a transformer with javascript for each row

dataconfig:

```
<dataSource name="EveneMongo" type="MongoDataSource" database="evene" />
 <document name="node">
  <entity name="livre" processor="MongoEntityProcessor"
   query="{'status':1, 'type':'book'}"
   collection="node"
   datasource="EveneMongo"
   transformer="script:book1">
      <filed column="_id" name="_id" mongoField="nid" />
      <entity name="livre_label"
              processor="MongoEntityProcessor"
              onError="continue"
              query="{'nid': ${livre.field_label_nid} }"

              collection="node"
              datasource="EveneMongo"
              transformer="script:book2">
   </entity
 </document>
</dataConfig>
```

and script js on same doc:

```
<script><![CDATA[

           function book1(row)
           {
                if(row.get('taxonomy') !== null)
                {
                    var taxo = JSON.parse(row.get('taxonomy'))

                    for(var i in taxo) {
                        if(taxo[i].name !== null  && taxo[i].vid !== null)
                        {
                            if(taxo[i].vid == 2)
                            {
                                row.put('taxonomy_names',taxo[i].name);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            function book2()
            {

            //...

            }
]]></script>
```